# Double Search and Print using Awk/Sed

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

I need a command to extract data from below data, For example I need data corresponding to `3_xloc_7` and `3_yloc_14` (Need to match both lines) and print until `3_lsep`.

```
a  
b  
3_xloc_7  
3_yloc_12  
c  
dsa  
gdf  
3_lsep  
3_xloc_6  
3_yloc_14  
asfdf  
dsdfgsd  
gsfsd  
tdg  
3_lsep  
3_xloc_7  
3_yloc_14  
a  
d  
g  
3_lsep
```

I used this command,

```
sed -n '/3_xloc_7/h;{/3_yloc_14/{x;G;};//,/3_lsep/p}'
```

but it gives wrong data.

Expected o/p:

```
3_xloc_7  
3_yloc_14  
a  
d  
g  
3_lsep
```

O/P: (It is giving o/p of `3_xloc_6` and `3_yloc_14`)

```
3_xloc_7  
3_yloc_14  
asfdf  
dsdfgsd  
gsfsd  
tdg    
3_lsep
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `gnu awk` (gnu due to multippel characters in Record Selector) may do:

```
awk -v RS='3_lsep' '/3_xloc_7/ && /3_xloc_14/ {print $0RS}' file

3_xloc_7
3_xloc_14
a
d
g
3_lsep
```

- `RS='3_lsep'` Set record selector to `3_lsep`.  Makes `awk` work with block of text.
- `/3_xloc_7/ && /3_xloc_14/` search for block containing both `3_xloc_7` and `3_xloc_14`
- `print $0RS` print block and record selector

Another version:

```
awk '/3_xloc_7/ {s=$0;t=NR} t+1==NR && /3_xloc_14/ {print s;f=1} f; /3_lsep/ {f=0}' file
3_xloc_7
3_xloc_14
a
d
g
3_lsep
```

- `/3_xloc_7/` if `3_xloc_7` is found, do
- - set `s=$0` (store the line) and `t=NR` (get current line number)
- `t+1==NR && /3_xloc_14/` if `t+1==NR` if this is the next line and it contains `/3_xloc_14/` do:
- - `{print s;f=1}` print previous line and set `f` to `1`
- `f;` if `f` is true do the default action, print
- `/3_lsep/ {f=0}` if line contains `3_lsep` set `f` to `0` to stop printing

Comment: The question isn't clear but I suspect that first script should be testing for `/3_xloc_7\n3_xloc_14/` instead of `/3_xloc_7/ && /3_xloc_14/` so it behaves the same as the 2nd script when `3_xloc_7` and `3_xloc_14` are separated by other lines and/or in the wrong order. I also suspect there should be word boundaries or something around each regexp term. Actually - that first script won't produce the desired output in general anyway as it'd print lines that occur before `3_xloc_7` (e.g. a b in the example if that first segment matched the regexp) - you'd need to sub() up to the regexp.

Comment: I've used it on real data, and it works perfectly :)